# Span button & Script in Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I trying a simple login function, but the button does not span, is always showing the login!.

I wanna the people press the login and then appears the login box but it is always visible! Can anybody help me?

layout.jade

```
doctype html5

    html
      head
        title #{title} - Main Page
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
        script(type='text/javascript')
          $('#toggle-login').click(function(){
          $('#login').toggle();
          });
      body
        header
          span#toogle-login.button(href='#login') Log in
          #login
            #triangle
            h1 Log in
            form
              input(type='email', placeholder='Email')
              input(type='password', placeholder='Password')
              input(type='submit', value='Log in')
          h1 Screen Shot Saver
          h2 Pictured your favourite websites
        .container
          .main-content
            block content
          .sidebar
            block sidebar
        footer
          p Running on node with Express, Jade and Stylus
```

Comment: Where are you including the jQuery library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all include the jquery script

```
script(src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js")
```

and then,in order to attach the click event on toggle-login, you have to include the click
function inside document ready, otherwise it won,t get attached.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#toggle-login').click(function(){
    $('#login').toggle();
  });
});
```

I hope this will do good for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I miss the jquery thing. I had the script of the document too. now all works! !! :)